# Length between circle curve and line

Tags: trigonometry, calculus-of-variations

[image]

Basically, while i was watching a calculus of variations video, the guy said that the length with infinitesmal $\theta$ equals to $R\sin(d\theta)$ instead i find it as $2R(\sin(d\theta/2))$? What is wrong with that? I guess since it is so small it basically converges to that value but how do we prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, just
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\ \sin(\theta)\ }{\ \theta\ } = 1$$
so
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\ \sin(2\theta)\ }{\ 2\sin(\theta)\ } = 1$$
hence
$$\sin(2\theta)\ \approx\ 2\sin(\theta)$$
for the theta angle small enough. And 'infinitesimal theta' means precisely that — the angle is *small*.

Compare, for example, Wikipedia [Infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal).

Comment: so we can also say Rsinθ equals Rθ as well which is the arc length